# How to get access to the Angular client via WAN or LAN

Tags: angular, iis, lan, wan

I'm trying to create a Angular web application hosted on my cpu.
I can deploy it on my IIS and it works fine.
This Application is separated in two, one client (Angular) and one API server (connected to SQL). The client is on port 80 and the server on port 8080. I can reach the API through WAN and LAN but when I try to reach the Angular client I get Failed to load resource: /flavicon.ico:1
the server responded with a status of 404 (not Found).
If I stop Angular client on the IIS and connect another project I have (A MVC monolite not made in Angular) it works. So frustrating.
Is there anyone that can help me with this?

Comment: What exactly is trying to connect to what? What do you mean "trying to reach angular client"?

Comment: Hi!I'm trying to reach the Angular-client from another computer. Not the computer from where it is located (from WAN and LAN). So the Angular-client runs smoothly from the computer where it is located but not from any other computer.

Comment: Usually favicon.ico is an icon to show next to title of website, just like you can see log of Microsoft when you access the site of Microsoft. So you can check the Angular application to see whether a file named favicon.ico under the directory. If nothing, use a image and rename to favicon.ico. Or add this in html file: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"/>.

Comment: Hi! The flavicon image is there.

Comment: @BruceZhang is there anything in the Angular application that needs to be change to allow connections to the web site from other computers than its origin?

Comment: Im not an expert on Angular. But if favicon.ico is there but application still return 404. It is not issue caused by IIS. Maybe application itself.